# issues installing mplcursors 'pip3 install mplcursors

Tags: python, mplcursors

I tried to install the mplcusrsors python modules. I use 'pip3 install mplcursors'
however it shows me the below error messages.
anyone know how to solve it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`find_namespace_packages` was added only in `setuptools` v50. Update it first:

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

Then, retry installing mplcursors.

// Somebody should file a bug or make a pull request to update their requirements